# Back UP file RDLs Creation in SSRS 2008 Automatically

Tags: reporting-services

Back UP RDLs Files Creation in SSRS 2008 
Automatically when we save it.
Can we resolve this ?

Like if there is report which name is AssetAmount.rdl

so when we updated it and save it 
then there is an autogenerated Rdl created as

**AssetAmount-BackUP.rdl
   AssetAmount-.rdl**
so there are two rdls files in a same folder

Comment: I too have this problem, I even have backup (2), backup (3) and even sometimes backup (4) - can't find the setting in VS2008 to change this! Did you find anything? cheers

Answer (score 4):

If the rdl version was in previous version say SSRS 2005 and now the rdl is accessed into SSRS 2008, the back up file is created while the report is upgraded. once the report is upgraded, delete the backup files and then onwards no backup files would be created.

Answer (score 2):

It took a while for me to notice that it was an issue for only the 2010 XML schema reports in my project.  Changing the `<Report xmlns>` tag to 2016 fixed the automatic backup file duplication.  And the report seemed to work just fine afterward too.

My post on this topic: [Visual Studio SSRS RDL Files creating a new file (backup) when opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52543379/visual-studio-ssrs-rdl-files-creating-a-new-file-backup-when-opened/52561608#52561608)

> VS open > right-click report > View Code > modify [Report xmlns] node > Save file...
>
> > 1. **FileThatKeepsDuplicating.rdl**
> >
> > > ORIGINAL: `<Report
> > >       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition"
> > >       xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">`
> > >
> > > NEW: `<Report
> > >       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition"
> > >       xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">`
> >
> > 2. **Repeat for all problem files with 2010 schema**
>
> You can open your files normally agian.  File backup duplication is resolved.

I am not sure why this fixes it.  If anyone has anymore information, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening whenever there is a change in the namespace of the RDL File. Refer to the URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143674%28v=sql.105%29.aspx. This is being done to safeguard the interest of the developer unfortunately unable to figure out specific options to stop this in BIDS.

Answer (score 0):

try takign the physical file and move it out of the folder, delete the copies, then add the file back into the project by going to "Add existing item".