# Visual Studio SSRS RDL Files creating a new file (backup) when opened

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

In VS I have a Solution file with SSRS Project.  Within the project there are 8 RDL files.  I am experiencing an issue when I open a file that it opens with an asterik (*) and upon closing the window it prompts that I save the file.  Then I went to the folder in Windows Explorer, at which time I noticed that Visual Studio was creating new files every time I open the file-- `<%FileName%>`, `<%FileName%- Backup>`, `<%FileName%- Backup (#)>`, `<....>`.

This is wierd.  Even wierder, the automatical file is created only for 4 of the RDL files in the Project (8 files in total).  Four files are always creating new backup files; and four files are acting normal.

> Does anyone know what is causing the files to automatically create
>   backups?

I checked the **VS File Properties** (*there is not much to see: FileName and Location*).  I also checked the **File Explorer Properties** (*it is not Read Only*).  My Project Folder **TargetServerVersion** is `SQL Server 2016 or later`.  The RDL files were downloaded from 2008 SSRS report server.  I compared the  tags for all the RPT files, after I found this SO thread ([Can I control the version of new SSDT reports in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071175/can-i-control-the-version-of-new-ssdt-reports-in-visual-studio)).

```
Problem files... (all say 2010)
* Daily Yum Products Daily Traffic Report.rdl
    <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition" 
    xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
* Load Planning Worksheet.rdl
    <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition" 
    xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
* Temporary Employees.rdl
    <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition" 
    xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
* Weekly Yum Products Daily Traffic Report.rdl
    <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition" 
    xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">

Working files... (some 2008, some 2016)
* BoJangles Data Export.rdl
    <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" 
    xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
* Load Comment Report.rdl
    <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" 
    xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
* OnBase Upload_AP Invoice Validation.rdl
    <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" 
    xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
* ScannedProduction.rdl
    <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" 
    xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">

Problem files (BACKUP COPY CREATED)...
* Daily Yum Products Daily Traffic Report.rdl
    <Report xmlns> all look the same as the original problem file
```

Other references:

I read this SO question but it's about a Project File not an RDL File: [visual studio keeps asking to save project file as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514458/visual-studio-keeps-asking-to-save-project-file-as).

Here is a screenshot of File Explorer and the VS Project RDL.

[image]

======================

**UPDATE**: I even tried deleting and re-adding the files.  The problem persists for the same 4 files; The other 4 files still work correctly.  The files are in version control, so I tried this... `delete files/ commit/ re-add the files/ commit/ tested opening the file/ Backup file auto created (still)`.

Removing RDL file that keep asking me to save...

```
Move these files 
FROM HERE...
  C:\Users\myUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SSRS\Project_ssrs2016\Decommissioned-2\
TO HERE...
  C:\Users\myUser\Downloads\Decommissioned-2 (backup)\

DELETED FILES FROM PROJECT
* Daily Yum Products Daily Traffic Report.rdl
* Load Planning Worksheet.rdl
* Temporary Employees.rdl
* Weekly Yum Products Daily Traffic Report.rdl
```

Re-Adding RDL file that keep asking me to save...

```
Move these files 
FROM HERE...
  C:\Users\myUser\Downloads\Decommissioned-2 (backup)\
TO HERE...
  C:\Users\myUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SSRS\Project_ssrs2016\Decommissioned-2\

ADDED FILES TO PROJECT
* Daily Yum Products Daily Traffic Report.rdl
* Load Planning Worksheet.rdl
* Temporary Employees.rdl
* Weekly Yum Products Daily Traffic Report.rdl
```

===========================

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was finally solved by editing the RDL file  tag for all the problems files from the 2010 to 2016 Report XML schema.  I did as follows: `(in VS) > right-click report > View Code > Paste the 2016 > Save`.

```
1) Daily Yum Products Daily Traffic Report.rdl
ORIGINAL
    <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition" 
    xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
NEW
    <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" 
    xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">

2) Repeated for all problem files with 2010 schema
3) Repeated for all problem files with 2010 schema
4) Repeated for all problem files with 2010 schema

* Auto Save issue is resolved.
```

I think what was causing the Backup Files to be created had something to do with a Visual Studio detecting a conflict in the Project TargetServerVersion and the RDL XML Schema.  Not sure why 2008 file works and 2010 doesn't work; regardless I left the 2008 as they were.

These SO posts had some helpful answers.

[Can I control the version of new SSDT reports in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071175/can-i-control-the-version-of-new-ssdt-reports-in-visual-studio)

[Back UP file RDLs Creation in SSRS 2008 Automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212100/back-up-file-rdls-creation-in-ssrs-2008-automatically)

Comment: This is only a solution if you can modify the target version of SSRS